# Как правильно осуществлять взаимодействие классов?

Tags: ооп, php, архитектура

Как правильно осуществлять взаимодействие классов?

Есть чистый класс для работы с бд, нужно сделать класс для работы с некоторыми данными(проверки всякие и т.п.), которые нужно получить из базы. Так вот как правильно с точки зрения архитектуры описывать новый класс? Как потомок класса для работы с базой - это как-то странно. Может передавать в конструктор указатель на экземпляр класса БД?

Comment: Еще можно в каждом методе объявлять глобальную переменную $db и с ней работать, но тогда уж лучше передавать в каждый метод ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Если "с точки зрения архитектуры" , то посмотрите паттерн проектирования "Декоратор". Еще есть АОП, при частой "работе с некоторыми данными(проверки всякие и т.п.)" может имеет смысл и его запилить. 
А вообще с данными из БД обычно особо не цацкаются: получают и показывают ;). Подразумевается, что вся обработка данных произошла до занесения данных в БД и там(в БД) они(данные) находятся в виде, который приложение сразу готово "отдать" клиенту. Посему посмотрите внимательно на архитектуру вашего приложения(возможно где-то вы не  правы ;)).
  А класс который работает с БД действительно лучше оформить как singleton причем при возрастании нагрузки быть готовым к организации пулов или распределению нагрузки.

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях делают из класса с БД "[синглтон](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)", а обработку неких данных оформляют в другом классе, в котором используют доступ к БД через "[синглтон](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)".